# Is there a way to show CPU and memory usage on a react-native app?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, profiler

I have tried to show the built in performance monitor but it does not show CPU or ram usage.

Is there a way to show the usage like in android studios profiler?

The sampling profiler does not work either.

Comment: Is it only for developing right? Not to use on production app

Comment: For me Yes.. @Vencovsky

Comment: @Vencovsky yes for developing. It's part of a uni project and we have to show the cpu and ram usage

Comment: @duronic did you find anything?

Answer (score -2):

You can watch my performance CPU 
With [this tool](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) as explained in 
[the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#profiling)

Comment: react-native-debugger is not for viewing CPU usage. Instead, it shows you a visual tree of you react/react-native application.